# How to sort the data that is already pulled out of the databse?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have created a HTML table based on a SQL table. The HTML is sorted by the products purchased date by default. I want to create a drop down list that contains options such as sort by price, quantity and etc.

I don't know if I should do this sorting in Javascript or SQL. I think it's easier to do it in Javascript, but I don't know how. If I have to do it by SQL sort, then I have to access the database again. I'm wondering if there is a way that I can just use this already existed HTML table to do the sorting?

Comment: yes, you can sort the data within the page,e .g. datatables.

Comment: @MarcB Is there a way that I can do it without using any extra plug-ins?

Comment: it's just dom modifications, so some basic javascsript code can do it. plugins just make it easier, e.g. jquery

Comment: Then store SQL response in JS variable as an array and on every option selected, manipulate that array and update the DOM..

Comment: http://tablesorter.com/docs/ may help..

Comment: @RayonDabre Thank you for your advice. This should help.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in vanilla or can you use jQuery?

Comment: @codenamejames I'm using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorttable.js`. Check this [link](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) for more reference...

Through this, the table content will be sorted based on the header click and no need to fetch the data from database again.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesharrington/cofzz0vm/3/) i created its the most basic sorting function i could think of customise it to your liking

Here is the JS

```
$('[data-sort]').click(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    colIndex = $this.index();
    $tbody = $this.closest('table').find('tbody');
    $rows = $tbody.find('tr');

    $rows.sort(function(a, b){
        var keyA = a.children[colIndex].innerText;
        var keyB = b.children[colIndex].innerText;
        // Compare the 2 dates
        if(keyA < keyB) return -1;
        if(keyA > keyB) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
    console.log($rows);
    $tbody.html($rows)
});
```

The way this code is laid out you have to have your data in a `tbody` and your sorting context in a `thead`

Comment: NOTE: This function is case sensitive! so Zebra will come before alpha